# Routing os.exec* output to string

Tags: python, http, cgi

I am trying to modify Python's http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler so that it will calculate `Content-Length` for CGI scripts. Below is the code from `/Lib/http/server.py` where the child process is spawned. I want to capture the output as a string so that I can calculate the size of it in bytes, and then send to wfile, but I am not sure how to route the output to a string instead of a file descriptor.

```
# Child
try:
    try:
        os.setuid(nobody)
    except os.error:
        pass
    os.dup2(self.rfile.fileno(), 0)
    os.dup2(self.wfile.fileno(), 1)
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
except:
    self.server.handle_error(self.request, self.client_address)
    os._exit(127)
```

(line 1129 - 1140 of http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/http/server.py)

Perhaps this is a very incorrect way to go about calculating the `Content-Length` so send me your suggested alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code already does everything you need (aside from setting the Content-Length header) in the else branch of the `if self.have_fork`.  For your use case, it seems like you would always want to use subprocesses and just get rid of the `if self.have_fork` part of the code.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think to look at the else portion. Do you know of any performance differences between os.exec and subprocess?

Comment: Not off-hand, but if you're concerned, you should profile to see if there's a significant difference.  Of course, that assumes that you also have a way to set Content-Length in the fork/exec case. :)